# bash * в переменной

Tags: bash

В чем разница:

```
d=$(date +%Y%m%d)  
f=$(ls -l /nmt/user/out/csv1$d.csv_*_response)
echo $f
```

Если выполнить команды из терминала то все работает, если выполнять из скрипта, то
выводит `/mnt/user/out/csv120160326.csv_*_response`, т.е `*` воспринимается как есть.
Как исправить?

Comment: у вас интерпретатор в оболочке какой? тот же, что и в скрипте? Бывает путаница с экранированием символов в `zsh`, у меня, по крайней мере. Поэтому не хочу переезжать с `bash` на `zsh` :)

Answer (score 1):

У меня что из терминала, что с помощью скрипта выводит **/mnt/user/out/csv120160326.csv__response**

О каком * речь?

Может Вы имеете ввиду `f=$(ls -l /nmt/user/out/csv1${d}.csv__response)` ?

**Обновление**

Тогда может так?

```
#!/bin/bash


d=$(date +%Y%m%d)
echo `ls -l /nmt/user/out/csv1${d}.csv_*_response`
```

Comment: Есть файлы у которых динамически создается кусок между _*_. Т.е. например csv20160326.csv_237452389476235_response. При поиске вместо этого куска подставляю * но ничего не выходит.